# Java Default Method - get type of subclass

Tags: java, generics, default-method

I have an interface in which I want to provide a default method to Serialize the inherited classes. I use a `JsonSerializer<T>` class to do serialization.

The method looks like:

```
public interface A
{
    public default String write()
    {
        new JsonSerializer</*Inherited class type*/>();
        // I've tried new JsonSerializer<this.getClass()>();  - Doesn't work

    }
}

public class AX implements A
{
}
```

So when I instantiate AX, I want to use the write method to serialize AX

```
AX inst = new AX();
String instSerialized = inst.write();
```

I need to pass the type of AX to the write method in A. is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you might be looking for is an interface declaration like this:

```
public interface A<T extends A<T>>
{
    public default String write()
    {
        new JsonSerializer<T>();
    }
}

public class AX implements A<AX>
{
}
```

Using [Self-bounding generics](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=136394) is sometimes useful, when you need to reference the current class as a generic argument. This is e.g. also done by the java `Enum` class: `abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`.

Answer (score 1):

The type parameters in the generics mechanism are a compile-time information, only. This type information is erased in the bytecode.

The exact class type of an object (which you can retrieve with `getClass()`) is a runtime information.

The conclusion: As you can only put static type names inside the generics brackets, there is no way to make any runtime calls there.

The only way to make your serializer somewhat covariant is to write

```
new JsonSerializer<? extends A>() ...
```

But the real question should be: What yre you trying to achieve? I feel, that your approach does not solve your problem.

Comment: Hey, what I'm trying to achieve is quite a bit to explain here... This is also the approach I've used this approach, and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you.

Comment: the information that generic types are strictly compile-time is widespread but not entirely true. see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2801291/178526

Answer (score 1):

Use generics in the interface

```
public interface A<T> {

    public default String write() {
        new JsonSerializer<T>();
        // I've tried new JsonSerializer<this.getClass()>();  - Doesn't work
    }
}

public class AX implements A<AX> {
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. this is a smart way to do it! Thanks.