# How to create an object of inherited generic class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Let's assume we got some classes with a hierarchy as follows:

```
abstract class Foo<T extends A>
class Bar extends Foo<B>
class Hesh extends Foo<C>

abstract class A
class B extends A
class C extends A
```

I wonder, if it is possible to write a code inside of **Foo**, that creates objects of type **B** or **C** when called from corresponding child class. For example

```
//inside of Foo body
public void populate() {
  //Something like
  Class current_t = T.class;
  current_t.getConstructor();
  //Create an instance of the object using reflection
}
```

As a result, I would like to have a method in parent class that creates objects, which type is defined in children classes.

Comment: That's a workaround I use at this moment. I am curious, if there are some language specifications i am not familiar with. Thanks for the hint though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, this is done by adding an abstract method to the parent class with the purpose to create such an instance, and let the child classes implement this method:

```
public abstract class Foo<T extends A> {
    protected abstract T newInstance();
}

public class Bar extends Foo<B> {
    @Override protected final T newInstance() { return new B(); }
}

public class Hesh extends Foo<C> {
    @Override protected final T newInstance() { return new C(); }
}
```

This way you have all knowledge about the concrete class that is to be instantiated (no need for reflection).

As a matter of fact, this is called the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

---

Unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve the concrete parameter type at runtime because they are erased. At least, you are not able to retrieve it in class `Foo`.

Another approach would be to provide a constructor that takes a type token:

```
public abstract class Foo<T extends A> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    protected Foo(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = Objects.requireNonNull(type);
    }
    private T newInstance() {
        return type.newInstance();
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo<B> {
    public Bar() {
        super(B.class);
    }
}

public class Hesh extends Foo<C> {
    public Hesh() {
        super(C.class);
    }
}
```

The disadvantage here is that those sub classes of `A` must have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Could you please explain, why there is a "final" in the method's declaration.

Comment: @Fattum - `final` has been added to prevent method overriding.

Comment: Thanks, that would be an answer.

Comment: @Fattum I could have added `final` to the classes itself (I personally would). This little keayword simply prevents overriding of overridable methods. Additionally, I added another approach to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seelenvirtuose's approaches are cleaner, but a there is a [somewhat hacky approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2801291/2646526) of using `getActualTypeArguments` from the superclass type to get the corresponding child class.  Once the child's class is obtained, you could use `newInstance` in your `populate` method to create instances via reflection, as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T populate() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    return ((Class<T>) (((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0])).newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Haha, noice! That's why programming makes fun!