# Generics Default Constructor Java

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Sample<T>{

 T data;

   Sample(){

     data = ????;

  }

}
```

How can i assign a default value to data ?

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type

Answer (score 8):

Bozho is right (you can't). If you definitely want it to start off with a value, make that value an argument to the constructor. For instance:

```
public class Sample<T> {
  T data;
  Sample(T data) {
     this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The type `T` [is erased](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at runtime, so you can't instantiate it.

If you pass a `Class` argument to the `Sample(..)` constructor, you can call `clazz.newInstance()`

Comment: *"You can't."* ... unless the default value is `null`.  :-)