# Getting the class of a generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the class of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type)

I have a method such as:

```
public <T> List<T> bar() {
    return new Baz<T.class>().toList();
}
```

`T.class` creates a compiler error. Is there some way to do this in Java, or is it impossible because of type erasure?

Comment: You can do this just fine: `return new Baz<T>().toList()`. There's no need for the method to know exactly what type `T` is at runtime in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type erasure prevents it. The best you can do is:

```
public <T> List<T> bar(Class<T> clazz) {
    // do something useful with the Class object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my limited knowledge this is undoable due to type erasure. However, some nice workarounds are [given in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java).

I would, however, see the non-workaround solution.