# How to determine type in a generic method in Java?

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I want a method that extracts the data from a JSON-object parsed before as the correct type. The JSONObject (rawdata) extends Map, so it looks like this:

```
private <Type> Type getValue(String key, Type def)
{
    if (!rawdata.containsKey(key)) return def;
    if (!(rawdata.get(key) instanceof Type)) return def;
    return (Type) rawdata.get(key);
}
```

The `instanceof` obviously generates a compile-time-error. The parameter `def` is the default-value, returned if the key is not available or has the wrong type. But `def` can also be null, so `def.getClass()` isn't working.

Any ideas how I can check the content of the Map-entry for the correct type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the class of a generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type)

Comment: I think you accidentally - an extra 'Type' in method signature.

Comment: @questzen no, it is a generic declaration, but it would have been more readable using standard conventions: `private <T> T getValue(String key, T def)`

Comment: You could have defined `rawdata` so that failing the `instanceof` test was in principle impossible. You haven't stated why you haven't done that, or even provided the definition of `rawdata`. Hard to answer without more info.

Comment: @EJP: I use a library for parsing JSON. It parses the data into a structure, that is basically a Map. As JSON-Values can be Numbers, Strings, more JSON-Object and Arrays this Map is untyped. rawdata is of that JSONObject-class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to type erasure, the only way to handle the case where the default value can be null is to have the method require an additional parmeter of type `Class` - which is generally better because it allows the default value to be a subclass of the required type.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to check for nulls (a null will count as any type, if this is undesired behaviour then you will also need to pass in the desired class).

```
private <T> T getValue(String key, T def)
{
    if (!rawdata.containsKey(key)) return def;

    Object value = rawdata.get(key);

    if (def == null) return (T) value; 
    // note that the above is inherently unsafe as we cannot 
    // guarantee that value is of type T

    // this if statement is the same as "value instanceOf Type"
    // is type safe, but not null safe
    if (def.getClass().isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
        return (T) value;
    } else {
        return def;
    }
}
```

A safer method signature would be:

```
private <T> T getValue(String key, T defaultValue, Class<T> defaultClass)
```

This way we can safely check the types match even when the default is null.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to accept a `Class` object for the return type in the case when no default value is given. You can just overload the function like:

```
private <T> T getValue(String key, Type defaultValue);

private <T> T getValue(String key, Class<T> type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the [Typesafe Heterogeneous Container](http://josefbetancourt.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/typesafeheterogeneouscontainerexample/) (THC) pattern from "Effective Java Second Edition" book by Joshua Bloch.

Basically, store the item's Class in the map when inserting. When retrieving you'll know the type is the same.

```
Map<Class, Map<String, Object>> rawData = ...
```