# How to get Class from type

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the class of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type)

Given the code like this:

```
   MyClass<SomeOtherClass> = new MyClass<SomeOtherClass>();

    public class MyClass<T> implements IMyClass<T> 
    {
       public MyClass()
       {
          //I need to get class of SomeOtherClass
       }
    }
```

Is it possbile to do something like this in Java?

**Updated for more clarity**

Comment: What about `MyClass.class`?

Answer (score 1):

The Java generic implementation does not allow you to know about the generic type parameters of a given instance. This is due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Too bad, it is not possible to get `SomeOtherClass.class` at your comment location.

Note that type erasure does not prevent to get the generic parameters of a declaration. For instance the following instance will be able to get the two `Function` interface generic parameter:

```
class ToStringFunction implement Function<Object,String> {
...
}
```

In your case the information is available the field declaration, which is not available within your class instance.