# How can i use a constructor of a generic class

Tags: java, generics

i got multiple classes which do basicly the same. I pass a JSONObject in the constructor an it sets some variabes.

Now i got some other classes which create those first classes and add them to a ArrayList. Now i want to merge the second classes to one using generics.

This is what I want to do:

```
 public class Data<T> {
     public ArrayList<T> data;

     public Data(String response1) {
         data = new ArrayList<T>();
         JSONArray ja;

         try {
              ja = new JSONArray(response1);
              for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                  data.add(new T(jo));
              }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

but it doesnt let me create an Instance of T with

```
new T(jo);
```

Would be nice if someone can help me

Comment: Just a question: if the "T" generic type is an interface in runtime, on a specific Data<T> instance, like say Data<java.util.List> how should "new T(something)" work?

Comment: It is a very strange. You even did not specify a superclass of generic type `T`. How it could understand such construction?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard trick for this situations: pass `Class<T>` along with the `String data` into the call, and add a setter for the `JSONObject`. This would let you call a parameterless constructor, like this:

```
interface WithJson {
    void setJson(JSONObject jo);
}

public class Data<T extends WithJson> {
    public Data(String response1, Class<T> type) {
        data = new ArrayList<T>();
        JSONArray ja;
        try {
             ja = new JSONArray(response1);
             for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                 T obj = type.newInstance();
                 object.setJson(jo);
                 data.add(obj);
             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Class<T>` has been modified in Java 5 to let you use it as a factory for the instances of that class. The call of `type.newInstance` is checked statically for type safety. The addition of the interface `WithJson` lets you call `setJson` method on the instances of `T` in a way that the compiler can check statically.

When you construct `Data<T>`, you need to pass the class being created, like this:

```
Data<MyContent> d = new Data(jsonString, MyContent.class);
```

Comment: If I create a new instance of Data what do i have to pass beside the String

Comment: @Cheetah That's an important thing that I missed in the original response. I edited the answer to show what to do. I also fixed a copy-paste error (I pasted `Class<T> type` into a wrong place).

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic factory interface.

```
public interface Factory<T>
{
    public T createFromJSONObject( JSONObject jo );
}
```

And now a modified constructor:

```
 public Data(
   String response1,
   Factory<T> factory
 ) {
     data = new ArrayList<T>();
     JSONArray ja;

     try {
          ja = new JSONArray(response1);
          for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
              data.add( factory.createFromJSONObject( jo ) );
          }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```