# Return class object of generic in java

Tags: java, generics

In the following code, I take a class T as generic "argument" and I need to return something like "T.class" in one of the methods. How do I do it?

```
public abstract class GenericLogPartitioner<K, V, T extends FileInputFormat<K, V>> extends LogPartitioner {



    @Override
    protected Class<? extends FileInputFormat> getInputFormatClass() {
        return T.getClass(); //what should be here. I need to return T
    }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type?rq=1 for why this generally cannot be done in this way. (It may still be possible through stronger reflection or other workarounds.)

Comment: You can resolve T using something like [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools). Class<T> t = (Class<T>)TypeResolver.resolveRawArguments(GenericLogPartitioner.class, getClass())[2];