# How to return class type of a generic class with generic?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have an interface like this;

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    Class<T> type();
}
```

If I want to implement this interface with an object, there is not any problem;

```
public OrderValidator implements Validator<Order>{ 
   Class<Order> type(){ 
      return Order.class; 
   }
}
```

But I can't implement this interface if I pass a Collection as generic type like this;

```
public CollectionValidator implements Validator<Collection<Item>>{

    Class<Collection<Item>> type(){
        //how can I implement this method to return type of Collection<Item> ?
    }
}
```

How can I implement `type()` method to return type of `Collection< Item>` ?

`Collection< Item>.class` does not work.

Comment: You can't without aditional information in the class: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/182636/1073063](http://stackoverflow.com/q/182636/1073063).

Comment: I'm actually passing that information when implementing the interface but I can't in this case. If I want to implement this interface with an object that is not a collection I can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to make it compile then try:

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    Class<T> type();
}
public static class CollectionValidator<Item> implements Validator<Collection<Item>>{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    public Class<Collection<Item>> type() {
        return (Class<Collection<Item>>) (Class<?>) Collection.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain the middle part with the cast Class<?>?

Comment: I knew I wanted to return `Collection.class` and simply added that to get rid of the `Cannot cast...` compiler error. The `(Class<?>)` cast removes the type information from the `Class<Collection>` which made the compiler think it was an error. The compiler does type erasure anyway, so casting `Class<A>` to `Class<B>` does not affect generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    Class<?> type();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface<Object>{

   @Override
   public Class<?> type() {
      //some collection to test
      List<String> lst = new LinkedList<>();

      return lst.getClass();
   }
}
```

Comment: That will return `List<String>` which is not `Collection<Item>`.

Comment: Actualy it returns `LinkedList`, however, I think I misunderstood the question. Sorry.