# select method based on generic type

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class MyClass<T extends Number> {
    T value;
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    public void setValueFromString(String s) {
        try {
            value = formatter.parse(s).doubleValue();
        } catch (ParseException e) { }
    }
}
```

Except, of course, `doubleValue()` isn't always the right method to use -- for example, if `T` is `Integer`, I want to use `intValue()`.  The only way I have found so far to deal with this is to make the `setValueFromString()` method abstract and only define it in subclasses when `T` has been specified.

Is there a way to define the `setValueFromString()` method in the generic class where it tests `T` and selects the appropriate conversion method from `Number`?  I have tried `instanceof`, `Class.isInstance()`, and `Class.isAssignableFrom()`, but none of those worked, giving compile-time errors about not being allowed to use `T`  that way.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the abstract approach. Just subclass it statically like `MyClass.OfInteger`, `MyClass.OfDouble` for whatever types you need. It's 5 minutes tops of boilerplate code and you're done.

Comment: you do realize that `NumberFormat.parse(s)` does not actually exist right? [`.parse(s)` is not a `static` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))

Comment: There is already a very good question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type

Comment: @Jarrod -- right, it isn't static, edited with the appropriate factory call

Comment: @mrak - doing branching logic based on `Type` is an anti-pattern at best and just adds complexity where there is none needed. You have to have an implementation per `Type` why not just code the conversion in there instead of this ridiculously complex approach. The entire approach is wrong. This is an X-Y Problem at best.

Answer (score 3):

#### You have to have a concrete class per Type regardless:

Trying to infer something like this from Generics at Runtime and branch the logic based on that information is only a path of pain and makes your code extremely hard to understand and easier to break.

What you are trying to do is more like an *abuse* of the type system than leveraging it. As soon as you get to testing for types with `instanceof` or `.getClass()` or any of the `TypeToken` *magic* you are probably doing it wrong, especially for something that can be done without all that mumbo-jumbo.

There are only so many `Number` subclasses, just hard code them and chain them where the first non-null return value from a `Converter` is the appropriate type.

Guava has something called [`Converter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Converter.html) just for things like this.

#### For example:

```
final static ShortConverter sc = new ShortConverter();
final static IntegerConverter ic = new IntegerConverter();
final static DoubleConverter dc = new DoubleConverter();

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    System.out.println("getNumber(\"1\").getClass().toString() = " + getNumber("1").getClass().toString());
    System.out.println("getNumber(\"64000\").getClass().toString() = " + getNumber("64000").getClass().toString());
    System.out.println("getNumber(\"3.14\").getClass().toString() = " + getNumber("3.14").getClass().toString());
}

public static Number getNumber(@Nonnull final String s)
{
    /* nest the firstNonNull() as deeply as you need for the limited
       number of types */
    return firstNonNull(sc.doForward(s), firstNonNull(ic.doForward(s), dc.doForward(s)));
}

public static class DoubleConverter extends Converter<String, Double>
{
    @Override
    protected String doBackward(@Nonnull final Double d) { return d.toString(); }

    @Override
    protected Double doForward(@Nonnull final String s) { return Doubles.tryParse(s); }
}

public static class IntegerConverter extends Converter<String, Integer>
{
    @Override
    protected String doBackward(@Nonnull final Integer i) { return i.toString(); }

    @Override
    protected Integer doForward(@Nonnull final String s) { return Ints.tryParse(s); }
}

public static class ShortConverter extends Converter<String, Short>
{
    @Override
    protected String doBackward(@Nonnull final Short s) { return s.toString(); }

    @Override
    protected Short doForward(@Nonnull final String s) { try { return Short.parseShort(s); } catch (NumberFormatException e) { return null; } }
}
```

#### Outputs:

```
getNumber("1").getClass().toString() = class java.lang.Short
getNumber("64000").getClass().toString() = class java.lang.Integer
getNumber("3.14").getClass().toString() = class java.lang.Double
```

#### In case how to apply this to the question is not obvious:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Number> 
{
    T value;
    final Converter<String,T> converter;

    public MyClass(final Converter<String,T> c)
    {
       this.converter = c;
    }

    public void setValueFromString(String s) 
    {
        this.value = this.converter.doForward(s);
    }
}
```