# Removing Warnings (Type safety: Unchecked cast from capture#2-of ? extends Template to T)

Tags: java, reflection

Inside my IF all 3 lines having warnings. How I can remove it without supress? Is there a better solution?

```
public void template() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
        if(templateResult == null){
            Class templateClass = getGenericTypeArgument(this.getClass(), 0);
            Constructor<? extends Template> constructor = templateClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{List.class, List.class});
            templateResult = (T) constructor.newInstance(listData, listaDataRes);       
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide code for this class?

Comment: Usually you should not see any warning. If you do it means that you have some non-standard things in your code

Comment: this test was in a isolated class.. I have 3 warnings:

            Class templateClass = getGenericTypeArgument(this.getClass(), 0);

Multiple markers at this line
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be 
  parameterized
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be 
  parameterized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove some of them by not using [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it):

```
Class<?> templateClass = getGenericTypeArgument(this.getClass(), 0);
//    ^
Constructor<? extends Template> constructor =
    templateClass.getConstructor(new Class<?>[]{List.class, List.class});
//                                         ^
```

It doesn't look to me like you can avoid the unchecked cast to `T`.

> Is there a better solution?

It looks to me like you might be using the `getGenericSuperclass().getActualTypeArguments()` thing and you can remove all warnings by passing the `Class<T>` as a parameter to the object ([shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182672/2891664)) instead.