# Java generics variable <T> value

Tags: java, generics

At the moment I am using the following code to do some filtering in jpa:

```
if (value.getClass() == Integer.class) {
   return cb.greaterThan(root.<Integer>get(field), (Integer) value);
} else if (value.getClass() == Long.class) {
   return cb.greaterThan(root.<Long>get(field), (Long) value);
} else if (value.getClass() == Float.class) {
   return cb.greaterThan(root.<Float>get(field), (Float) value);
} else if (value.getClass() == Date.class) {
   return cb.greaterThan(root.<Date>get(field), (Date) value);
}
```

How can i reduce this block to one line like that?

```
return cb.greaterThan(root.<value.getClass()>get(field), value);
```

So i need to replace the T value in < T > with my class type. Sadly i am not that good in java generics. Does anybody has an idea? Is it even possible?

root is of the following type: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get%28java.lang.String%29

edit: here is the full class i want to write:

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

public class FilterExpression {

    public static final Integer BEGINS_WITH = 0;
    public static final Integer ENDS_WITH = 1;
    public static final Integer CONTAINS = 2;
    public static final Integer EQUAL = 3;
    public static final Integer NOT_EQUAL = 4;
    public static final Integer GREATER_THAN = 5;
    public static final Integer GREATER_EQUAL_THAN = 6;
    public static final Integer LESS_THAN = 7;
    public static final Integer LESS_EQUAL_THAN = 8;
    private static final Map<String, Integer> OPERATOR_MAPPING;

    static {
        Map<String, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
        temp.put("bw", BEGINS_WITH);
        temp.put("ew", ENDS_WITH);
        temp.put("ct", CONTAINS);
        temp.put("eq", EQUAL);
        temp.put("nq", NOT_EQUAL);
        temp.put("gt", GREATER_THAN);
        temp.put("gq", GREATER_EQUAL_THAN);
        temp.put("lt", LESS_THAN);
        temp.put("lq", LESS_EQUAL_THAN);
        OPERATOR_MAPPING = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
    }

    private String field;
    private Integer operator;
    private Object value;

    public FilterExpression(String field, String operator, String value, Class c) {
        this.field = field;
        setOperator(operator);
        setValue(value, c);
    }

    public Boolean validate() {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(field) || operator == null || value == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Class c = value.getClass();

        if (c == String.class) {
            return operator >= BEGINS_WITH && operator <= NOT_EQUAL;
        } else if (c == Integer.class || c == Float.class || c == Double.class) {
            return (EQUAL >= EQUAL && operator <= LESS_EQUAL_THAN);
        } else if (c == Boolean.class) {
            return operator == EQUAL || operator == NOT_EQUAL;
        } else if (c == Identification.Type.class) {
            return operator == EQUAL || operator == NOT_EQUAL;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Integer getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void setOperator(String operator) {
        this.operator = OPERATOR_MAPPING.get(operator.toLowerCase());
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String s, Class c) {
        try {
            if (Boolean.class == c) {
                this.value = validateBoolean(s);
            } else if (Integer.class == c) {
                this.value = Integer.parseInt(s);
            } else if (Float.class == c) {
                this.value = Float.parseFloat(s);
            } else if (Identification.Type.class == c) {
                this.value = Identification.Type.parse(Integer.parseInt(s));
            } else {
                this.value = s;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            this.value = null;
        }
    }

    public <R> Predicate toPredicate(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<R> root) {
        if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.EQUAL)) {
            return cb.equal(root.get(field), value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.NOT_EQUAL)) {
            return cb.notEqual(root.get(field), value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.CONTAINS)) {
            return cb.like(root.<String>get(field), "%" + value + "%");
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.ENDS_WITH)) {
            return cb.like(root.<String>get(field), "%" + value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.BEGINS_WITH)) {
            return cb.like(root.<String>get(field), value + "%");
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.GREATER_THAN)) {
            if (value.getClass() == Integer.class) {
                return cb.greaterThan(root.<Integer>get(field), (Integer) value);
            } else if (value.getClass() == Float.class) {
                return cb.greaterThan(root.<Float>get(field), (Float) value);
            } else if (value.getClass() == Date.class) {
                return cb.greaterThan(root.<Date>get(field), (Date) value);
            }
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.GREATER_EQUAL_THAN)) {
            if (value.getClass() == Integer.class) {
                return cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Integer>get(field), (Integer) value);
            } else if (value.getClass() == Float.class) {
                return cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Float>get(field), (Float) value);
            } else if (value.getClass() == Date.class) {
                return cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(field), (Date) value);
            }
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.LESS_THAN)) {
            if (value.getClass() == Integer.class) {
                return cb.lessThan(root.<Integer>get(field), (Integer) value);
            } else if (value.getClass() == Float.class) {
                return cb.lessThan(root.<Float>get(field), (Float) value);
            } else if (value.getClass() == Date.class) {
                return cb.lessThan(root.<Date>get(field), (Date) value);
            }
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.LESS_EQUAL_THAN)) {
            if (value.getClass() == Integer.class) {
                return cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Integer>get(field), (Integer) value);
            } else if (value.getClass() == Float.class) {
                return cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Float>get(field), (Float) value);
            } else if (value.getClass() == Date.class) {
                return cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(field), (Date) value);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What type is `root`? How is the `get()` method defined? What is `cb`?

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: Note that the result of `root.<Integer>get(field)` is no different from `root.<Long>get(field)`, since that type isn't available at runtime; the only valid safe value that can be returned from the method is `null`.

Comment: Depending on how `root` and `value` are defined, `cb.greaterThan(root.get(field), value);` can be enough. The only constraint that I can see in the javadoc on `T` is `<T extends java.lang.Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: So, what is the type that `cb.greaterThan()` expecting?

Comment: please provide the full method

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i added the hole class i try to write

Comment: @RealSkeptic here is the description: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#greaterThan-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-

Comment: what is the class Root?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto its from javax.persistence.criteria.Root. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Root.html

Comment: Have you tried `cb.greaterThan(root.get(field),(Comparable<?>)value)`?

Comment: `EQUAL >= EQUAL` - equality is a hard goal

Comment: To some extend you may use the Java SE class [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) with its conversion functions like `toLong`.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to determine the type of a generic at runtime. Generic type is compile time Java process. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) You should read the full documentation about this.

Comment: @RealSkeptic gives me a non suitable method found.

Comment: @MickaëlB the answer from Codebender is not bad but i don´t know how to construct the generic class with a variable type. So you are saying that´s not possible?

Comment: @user2630406 I already had this problem before and I had no choice to use a solution like Codebender proprosed.

Comment: @perotom please, see my comment on Codebender's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the two answers from codebender and nicolas filotto i was able to do it.
I had to remove the setValue method to put it outside the class. So here is the complete class:

```
public class FilterExpression<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public static final Integer BEGINS_WITH = 0;
    public static final Integer ENDS_WITH = 1;
    public static final Integer CONTAINS = 2;
    public static final Integer EQUAL = 3;
    public static final Integer NOT_EQUAL = 4;
    public static final Integer GREATER_THAN = 5;
    public static final Integer GREATER_EQUAL_THAN = 6;
    public static final Integer LESS_THAN = 7;
    public static final Integer LESS_EQUAL_THAN = 8;
    private static final Map<String, Integer> OPERATOR_MAPPING;

    static {
        Map<String, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
        temp.put("bw", BEGINS_WITH);
        temp.put("ew", ENDS_WITH);
        temp.put("ct", CONTAINS);
        temp.put("eq", EQUAL);
        temp.put("nq", NOT_EQUAL);
        temp.put("gt", GREATER_THAN);
        temp.put("gq", GREATER_EQUAL_THAN);
        temp.put("lt", LESS_THAN);
        temp.put("lq", LESS_EQUAL_THAN);
        OPERATOR_MAPPING = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
    }

    private String field;
    private Integer operator;
    private T value;

    public FilterExpression(String field, String operator, T value) {
        this.field = field;
        setOperator(operator);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Boolean validate() {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(field) || operator == null || value == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Class c = value.getClass();

        if (c == String.class) {
            return operator >= BEGINS_WITH && operator <= NOT_EQUAL;
        } else if (c == Integer.class || c == Float.class || c == Double.class || c == Date.class) {
            return (EQUAL >= EQUAL && operator <= LESS_EQUAL_THAN);
        } else if (c == Boolean.class) {
            return operator == EQUAL || operator == NOT_EQUAL;
        } else if (c == Identification.Type.class) {
            return operator == EQUAL || operator == NOT_EQUAL;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Integer getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void setOperator(String operator) {
        this.operator = OPERATOR_MAPPING.get(operator.toLowerCase());
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <R> Predicate toPredicate(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<R> root) {
        if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.EQUAL)) {
            return cb.equal(root.<T>get(field), value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.NOT_EQUAL)) {
            return cb.notEqual(root.<T>get(field), value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.CONTAINS)) {
            return cb.like(root.<String>get(field), "%" + value + "%");
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.ENDS_WITH)) {
            return cb.like(root.<String>get(field), "%" + value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.BEGINS_WITH)) {
            return cb.like(root.<String>get(field), value + "%");
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.GREATER_THAN)) {
            return cb.greaterThan(root.<T>get(field), (T) value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.GREATER_EQUAL_THAN)) {
            return cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<T>get(field), (T) value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.LESS_THAN)) {
            return cb.lessThan(root.<T>get(field), (T) value);
        } else if (Objects.equals(operator, FilterExpression.LESS_EQUAL_THAN)) {
            return cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<T>get(field), (T) value);
        } 
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could make the whole class generic.

```
public class FilterExpression<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    //Make value to be type T instead of Object.
    T value;

    // And you could easily do,
    ...
    return cb.greaterThan(root.<T>get(field), value);
}
```

Comment: i also thought about that but how do you set the type of the generic class in the setValue method?

Comment: This is the *start* of what needs to happen...there are some logistics issues in why the logic for different classes all need to live in this one.

Comment: Ok but how can i construct this generic class with an variable type? for example currently i determine the type from a Map<String, Class>.

Comment: @user2630406 You can't determine a class from a generic type. You need to pass the class as a parameter to the method who need it. Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 2):

As the code of your method is complex since everything is mixed, if you don't intend to refactor your method for me the simplest solution by far is relying on raw types as next:

```
return cb.greaterThan(root.<Comparable>get(field), (Comparable) value);
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic I agree that it is not an ideal solution but regarding the code of the OP's method where everything is mixed it would be the easiest one by far unless he refactors his code. If you have a simplest solution, please share